# Unable to install pylint on Macbook

Tags: python, macos, pip

I installed python 3.7 on my MacBook using the anaconda distribution. I installed some packages too, and was doing a python course. In between I got a message on my terminal saying zsh is your shell and please run (...some command...) to change the shell. I did that.
Today when trying to install pylint using pip I got an error as below.

```
anilkhare@Anils-MacBook-Air ~ % pip install pylint
zsh: command not found: pip
```

I tried to install pip using

'''
sudo easy_install pip

'''
After that I checked the pip version with

'''
anilkhare@Anils-MacBook-Air ~ % pip -V

pip 20.0.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-20.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)

'''
Then I installed pylint using

'''
pip install pylint

'''

But after successful installation of pylint, when I try to run it for .py file, I get a message

'''
zsh:command not found : pylint

'''

Comment: `zsh` is probably not configured to work with `conda`. Can you run `conda` commands in your `zsh`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't install with pip if can use conda instead. If `conda` isn't recognized too, navigate to your `../Anaconda/condabin` folder and run

```
conda init --all
```

Then restart your shell and

```
> conda activate
(base) conda install pylint
```

Comment: conda is not recognized and I could not find the location though Anaconda is installed.

Comment: So what makes you believe that Anaconda is installed if you can't find it?

Comment: Anaconda navigator is working. I am able to run jupyter notebooks. The issue started (I believe )after I changed the shell to zsh from bash. The thing is I have no software or programming background and using a mac for the first time and trying to learn python...

Comment: But then stick to Anaconda Navigator and don't mix it with pip. Chances are high you already messed up your installation. You can do everything from the Navigator. Imho, Stackoverflow is not the best resource for beginners. You can neither properly ask questions nor can you make use of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python installed [you can do the following](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py)

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

It will install pip and you will be able to use it going forward.

Comment: when I run the second command - python get-pip.py I get a syntax error    anilkhare@Anils-MacBook-Air ~ % python get-pip.py         
  File "get-pip.py", line 1
    <html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It seems that the curl command hasn't executed in the expected way. Please show me output of `curl -s https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | head`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on my mac. Thanks Vkozyrev. curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py